# Tampermonkey run script on specific tab

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm on learning Tempermonkey and it's userscripts. And I have some questions.

I want to run one script for all firefox opened containers but this script must have different settings according the container's tab it ran on. Like some data and different conditions in some functions.

I tried to use `GM_getTab` for that but it sends me an empty object for some reasons.

```
// @grant GM_getTab

GM_getTab(function (e) {
    console.log(e); // 'e is empty in console and in debug window either'
});
```

So basically how to use this function for my task?

P.S. Firefox: **Portable 93.0 (64-bit)**

Answer (score 0):

Omg why always like this, just asked the question and found the solution in next 10 minutes :D

So the solution is:

```
(async () => {
    const tabObj = await GM.getTab();

    // You first have to define ID for all tabs you need, then just comment this part
    tabObj.id = Math.random();
    GM_saveTab(tabObj); // update the object

    // get all stored objects
    const tabsDatabase = await GM.getTabs();
    const dbL = Object.keys(tabsDatabase).length;

    console.log('Script-owned tab:', tabObj); // Current tab
    console.log('Script-owned tabs count:', tabsDatabase); // All opened tabs
})();
```